# Cоединить 2 массива в один через цикл

Tags: c++

Решил соединить 2 массива в один через цикл, но почему-то когда он заполняет 1 элемент 2 массива, то печатает 1 элемент 1 массива

```
int mas_1[2] = {2,2};
int mas_2[2] = {223,231};
int *mas_3 = new int[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (i < 2) { mas_3[i] = mas_1[i]; }
    else { mas_3[i] = mas_2[4-i];}
}
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    std::cout <<(mas_3[i])<< std::endl;

}
delete mas_2;
delete mas_1;
```

Comment: Зачем `delete mas_2;` и `delete mas_1;`?

Comment: препод требовал освободить первые 2 после заполнения третьего

Comment: И как, получилось? :) массивы 1,2 выделены на стеке. `delete` для этого не подходит.

Comment: Нет. Переменные на стеке освобождаются при выходе из блока, в котором они определены, автоматически. А вот `mas_3` уже надо удалять через `delete[]`. Именно с квадратными скобками, т.к. это массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Распишите:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (i < 2) { mas_3[i] = mas_1[i]; }
    else { mas_3[i] = mas_2[4-i];}
}
```

при `i = 0` и `1` выполняется `mas_3[i] = mas_1[i];`, как вы и хотите, но дальше - при `i = 2` у вас выполняется `mas_3[2] = mas_2[2];`, а при `i = 3` - `mas_3[3] = mas_2[1];`.

Так что у вас еще и выход за пределы массива...

Замените `4-i` на `i-2`...